# How do I correctly create another thread instance from the same Runnable?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have a class called `Flash` that has a `Runnable` defined in it.

```
class Flash
{
Runnable slow = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){ 
             //Do stuff here
        }
    }
};
Thread slowThread = null; //Just declared a Thread variable

//more stuff here

}
```

Now I have a method named `blinkslow()` that creates a new thread class object using the `slow` runnable:

```
void blinkSlow()
{
    if(!threadRunning) //Boolean to make sure the thread is not running(works fine)
    {
        slowThread=null;
        slowThread = new Thread(slow);
        slowThread.start();
        threadRunning = true;
    }

}
```

Now, when the `run()` method finishes its job, in its last statement, it sets this boolean flag `threadRunning` to false, and exits.

Then when I call the method `blinkslow()` the second time, the thread does not run. Why is this happening?
I've made sure that:

- The thread has stopped i.e. completes its `run()` method before calling the `blinkshow()` method again.
- I'm not trying to re-start the same thread again, as the statement `slowThread = new Thread(slow);` creates a new instance of the Thread class with my Runnable each time its called.

How can I create another instance of the runnable again after it has ended its execution for the first time? What I've done above isn't working for the second time, and I have no clue why.

Comment: We are missing the declaration of `threadRunning`. Is it a class instance? I suspect that this variable is not set to false correctly after execution.

Comment: Swap the `slowThread.start();` and `threadRunning = true;` calling `start()` creates a "happens before" relationship for all other modifications to variables up to that point, your thread may start running before `start` returns

Comment: @Xvolks that flag is declared in the same `Flash` class, just above this Runnable. My code until now is fairly simple, there aren't much things happening and I've confirmed that this flag is set and works correctly.

Comment: Your assignment, `slowThread=null;` serves no purpose, since your very next statement is an assignment to the same variable.

Comment: Re, "My code...is simple..."  There is nothing obviously wrong with the part that you have shown us.  The problem must be somewhere in the part that you have _not_ shown us.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, it made me go through the part I've not shown, there was an extra flag that was not set, which caused the entire problem of thread not being able to be called the second time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what I was doing wrong, and I feel silly right now. I had another flag `stop` (a boolean variable) inside the run method. I forgot to unset it after first run.

The above code will run fine without any problem, unless you were me.

Answer (score -2):

When a thread is finshed, he enters the "dead" state, and it cannot be used anymore.
To use the run method, you need to create à new instance of the thread object.

Comment: So the `Runnable` variable `slow` must be declared again somehow each time for the thread?

Comment: The code example does not show any attempt to re-use a `Thread` object, and there is no reason why the `Runnable` object can not be reused.